# C Programming question about power, factorial, and combination

Tags: c

I have been assigned a question about solving an equation with power factorial and combination. In this question, I was assigned to code power and factorial with a for loop. And I think I have done that (they are working one by one). Also in the main function, I need to calculate an equation. So here is my code, it looks right to me. but eventually I am getting a "Floating point exception (core dumped)" error. Any help can be nice, I actually don't want the right answer, if you can explain why am I getting this error, that would be helpful. Thank you. (I cannot upload a photo because of reputation things if there is a way to share photo I will.)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int factorial(int n){
    int i,result=1;
    for(i=1; i<=n; ++i){
        result = result*i;
    }
    return result;
}

int power(int x,int y){ // base -> x , exponent -> y
    int result=1;
    for(int i=1;i<=y;i++) // multiply x, y times
        result*=x;
    return result;
}

int combination(int n,int r){
    return factorial(n)/(factorial(r)*factorial(n-r));
}

int main()
{
    double ans=0;
    int n;
    printf("Enter n : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        int denominator = 0,numerator = 0; // set denominator, numerator to 0 because we are going to add to them
        for(int z=1;z<=n-i;z++)
            numerator += power(i,z);
        
        for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)
            denominator += ((power(j,n)*combination(n,j))/factorial(n));
        
        ans = ans + (numerator/denominator);
    }
    printf("Resut is : %f",ans);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You probably have division by zero somewhere

Comment: you need to optimize or you will get integer overflow.

Comment: Also this code won't compile. You have `answer` defined, but not `ans`. So it is not the code that can give this error. Please post [mcve].

Comment: Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and try to figure out the problem yourself. If you don't understand why it happens, you can at least explain *where* it appears to happen - which operation is failing, and what the input values are. BTW: It's spelled `numerator`.

Comment: all of your division probably needs to be using `double`, not `int`, otherwise you get zeros whenever denominator is bigger than numerator

Comment: since you are dealing in integers your denominator can be 0 as 1/x where x>1 is 0 for integers

Comment: Thank you for all for answers, everyone helped me well. And thank you for the grammar checks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure you want to perform integer arithmetic, you need to ensure the denominator is not zero before the division:

```
if (denominator != 0)
    ans = ans + (numerator/denominator);
```

In the first iteration of the outer for loop, `i=1`, which means the denominator loop will execute only once, setting the denominator to: `1^n * C(n 1) / n! = 1/(n-1)!`, which is 0 in integer division (unless `n=1` or `n=2`).

If you did not intend to perform integer arithmetic, then change the type of the `denominator` to `double`:

```
double denominator = 0, numerator = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you, checking whether the denominator is zero or not worked. Also, I get the logic of It thank you all for helping.